# Matching Chinese characters with regular expressions (php)

Tags: php, regex, unicode, cjk

Could you please point me to the mistake in my regular expression?

`/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]*[.\s]*\[\/m\][\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]/u`

My string starts with a Chinese character (`[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]`), followed by any character and ends with '[/m]' and another Chinese character. So the string possibly could look like:

`我... some text goes here (contains any characters including spaces and new lines)... [/m]我`

But unfortunately my regular expression doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Does it match too much or too little or not at all?

Answer (score 3):

Matching Chinese characters with regular expressions (php)

```
<?php 

# this is our regx /\p{Han}+/u

$string='我... some text goes here (contains any characters including spaces and new lines)... [/m]我'; 

if(preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $string)){
echo "chinese here"; 
}

if(preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $string)){

#get all chinese characters in one array 
preg_match_all('/\p{Han}+/u',$string,$matches);

print_R($matches[0]);

}
?>
```

chinese here

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 我
            [1] => 我
        )

)
```

You can do a foreach and replace your desired characters .

Comment: Please add some explanation - what exactly should that code do?

Comment: @NicoHaase are you serious lol 
Matching Chinese characters with regular expressions (php)

Comment: What do you mean by "serious"? I have not seen the `\p` part before, and the current state of your answer is definitely better. Others should be able to learn from your code, that's why one-liners of code raise the attention

Comment: @NicoHaase \p stands for code points . you can find a lot more here 

.https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: That's what I've learned in the meantime too. But to make it a good answer, you should have mentioned that in the first place such thath others can learn why your code might be best suited to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably want to replace the first '*' with '+' to ensure you have at least one matching character in the initial spot and you can drop the character group with '\s' and just use '.' as that will match any character.  Also, if this is to be a complete line I would start the regex with '^' and end it with '$'.

Answer (score 1):

1. If there should only be one Chinese character at the beginning, drop the first '*'.
2. However you should keep the '[.\s]', because '.' doesn't match
   newlines (I think).
3. Once that's done, make sure the problem comes from the regexp and not from the php code.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}][.\s]*\[\/m\][\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]/um
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+.+\[\/m\][\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]
```

Which matches your description:

`[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+` --> One or more chars between 4E00 and 9FA5.

`.+` --> One or more other chars

`\[\/m\]` --> [/m]

`[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]` --> One char between 4E00 and 9FA5